# vpn conflict with dhclient on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network-manager, vpn, dhclient

I'm trying to keep a VPN connection to the internet running on my Ubuntu desktop all the time. I'm finding that when `dhclient` runs periodically, presumably to renew my DHCP lease, things go poorly and the machine is left without any internet connection. I resolve by rebooting. This problem only happens when VPN is running, so I'm assuming that's where the problem lies.

My initial thought was to bring VPN down/up using the enter/exit hooks for `dhclient`, but I'm open to other/better solutions. Log attached.

```
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB dhclient[1242]: DHCPREQUEST of 24.5.188.10 on enp2s0 to 69.252.97.6 port 67 (xid=0x10daacd5)
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB dhclient[1242]: DHCPACK of 24.5.188.10 from 69.252.97.6
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8270]   address 24.5.188.10
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8271]   plen 20 (255.255.240.0)
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8271]   gateway 24.5.176.1
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8272]   server identifier 69.252.97.6
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8272]   lease time 345380
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8273]   hostname 'UB'
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8273]   nameserver '75.75.75.75'
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8274]   nameserver '75.75.76.76'
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8274]   domain name 'hsd1.ca.comcast.net.'
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382412.8275] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed bound -> bound
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB dbus[798]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB dhclient[1242]: bound to 24.5.188.10 -- renewal in 162391 seconds.
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB dbus[798]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [enp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 28 05:26:52 UB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [enp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 28 05:26:58 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPREQUEST(enp3s0) 10.42.0.137 30:8c:fb:85:67:14
Apr 28 05:26:58 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPACK(enp3s0) 10.42.0.137 30:8c:fb:85:67:14
Apr 28 05:27:36 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPREQUEST(enp3s0) 10.42.0.70 ec:66:d1:01:f8:41
Apr 28 05:27:36 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPACK(enp3s0) 10.42.0.70 ec:66:d1:01:f8:41
Apr 28 05:28:07 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPREQUEST(enp3s0) 10.42.0.211 c8:69:cd:41:cb:e0
Apr 28 05:28:07 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPACK(enp3s0) 10.42.0.211 c8:69:cd:41:cb:e0 Apple-TV-8
Apr 28 05:28:27 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPREQUEST(enp3s0) 10.42.0.211 c8:69:cd:41:cb:e0
Apr 28 05:28:27 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPACK(enp3s0) 10.42.0.211 c8:69:cd:41:cb:e0 Apple-TV-8
Apr 28 05:29:19 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: BOOTP(enp3s0) 00:21:b7:91:00:ea no address configured
Apr 28 05:29:19 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: BOOTP(enp3s0) 00:21:b7:91:00:ea no address configured
Apr 28 05:29:22 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPDISCOVER(enp3s0) 169.254.1.107 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:29:22 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPOFFER(enp3s0) 10.42.0.231 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:29:26 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPDISCOVER(enp3s0) 169.254.1.107 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:29:26 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPOFFER(enp3s0) 10.42.0.231 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:29:34 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPDISCOVER(enp3s0) 169.254.1.107 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:29:34 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPOFFER(enp3s0) 10.42.0.231 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:32:53 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382773.6997] device (enp2s0): link disconnected (deferring action for 4 seconds)
Apr 28 05:32:53 UB kernel: [143121.130149] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
Apr 28 05:32:53 UB systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 1h 17min 7.397693s random time.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382777.8110] device (enp2s0): link disconnected (calling deferred action)
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382777.8118] device (enp2s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [100 20 40]
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382777.8451] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1242
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382777.8452] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382777.8465] dhcp6 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1674
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382777.8465] dhcp6 (enp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Withdrawing address record for 24.5.188.10 on enp2s0.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv4 with address 24.5.188.10.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Interface enp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Withdrawing address record for 2001:558:6045:bf:393a:c4b4:7335:5239 on enp2s0.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address 2001:558:6045:bf:393a:c4b4:7335:5239.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Registering new address record for fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b on enp2s0.*.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b on enp2s0.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Interface enp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382777.8525] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB dnsmasq[1318]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB dnsmasq[1318]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB dnsmasq[1318]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB dnsmasq[1209]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB dnsmasq[1209]: using nameserver 127.0.1.1#53
Apr 28 05:32:57 UB dnsmasq[1209]: cleared cache
Apr 28 05:33:00 UB kernel: [143127.509123] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB postfix[17186]:  * Reloading Postfix configuration...
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB postfix[17190]: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB postfix[17190]: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB postfix[17190]: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB postfix/master[2114]: reload -- version 3.1.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB postfix[17186]:    ...done.
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382787.9554] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB dnsmasq[1318]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB dnsmasq[1318]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
Apr 28 05:33:07 UB dnsmasq[1318]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: message repeated 2 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.0142] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: message repeated 49 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[7148]: send SIGTERM
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB kernel: [143135.464571] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): tun0: link is not ready
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: message repeated 2 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.0286] vpn-connection[0x278c1e0,5587a2f5-130f-4193-acfa-396a698f6f2b,"ipvanish-US-San-Jose-sjc-a12",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.0286] vpn-connection[0x278c1e0,5587a2f5-130f-4193-acfa-396a698f6f2b,"ipvanish-US-San-Jose-sjc-a12",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.0298] device (enp2s0): link connected
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.0331] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed') [100 10 41]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.0334] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: message repeated 24 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB dnsmasq[1318]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: message repeated 155 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.0729] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: message repeated 55 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB dbus[798]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: SIGTERM received, sending exit notification to peer
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: message repeated 32 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB dbus[798]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-down' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-down' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [enp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-dispatcher: req:3 'down' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: message repeated 168 times: [ write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-dispatcher: req:2 'down' [enp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB nm-dispatcher: req:3 'down' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.1286] policy: auto-activating connection 'Built-in ethernet'
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.1302] device (enp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Built-in ethernet' (91c9448c-6ed0-3a75-8724-25adc0f0819d)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.1338] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.1339] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.1344] device (enp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.1350] device (enp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.1354] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382788.1399] dhcp4 (enp2s0): dhclient started with pid 17250
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB gnome-session[1645]: message repeated 3 times: [ (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent]
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB dhclient[17250]: DHCPREQUEST of 24.5.188.10 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1be24cda)
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Apr 28 05:33:08 UB gnome-session[1645]: message repeated 3 times: [ (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed]
Apr 28 05:33:09 UB nm-openvpn[7148]: write UDPv4: Network is unreachable (code=101)
Apr 28 05:33:09 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b.
Apr 28 05:33:09 UB avahi-daemon[795]: New relevant interface enp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 28 05:33:09 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Registering new address record for fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b on enp2s0.*.
Apr 28 05:33:10 UB NetworkManager[841]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[7148]: send SIGKILL
Apr 28 05:33:10 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382790.0307] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Apr 28 05:33:10 UB NetworkManager[841]: (nm-openvpn-service:7141): nm-openvpn-WARNING **: openvpn[7148] died with signal 9
Apr 28 05:33:11 UB dhclient[17250]: DHCPREQUEST of 24.5.188.10 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1be24cda)
Apr 28 05:33:12 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:33:12] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 28 05:33:12 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:33:12] offline
Apr 28 05:33:14 UB dhclient[17250]: DHCPREQUEST of 24.5.188.10 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1be24cda)
Apr 28 05:33:18 UB dhclient[17250]: DHCPREQUEST of 24.5.188.10 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1be24cda)
Apr 28 05:33:25 UB dhclient[17250]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x25a94a35)
Apr 28 05:33:28 UB dhclient[17250]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x25a94a35)
Apr 28 05:33:36 UB dhclient[17250]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x25a94a35)
Apr 28 05:33:40 UB kernel: [143168.263079] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
Apr 28 05:33:40 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382820.8325] device (enp2s0): link disconnected (deferring action for 4 seconds)
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382824.8129] device (enp2s0): link disconnected (calling deferred action)
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382824.8136] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-config -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [70 20 40]
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382824.8304] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 17250
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382824.8305] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed unknown -> done
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b on enp2s0.
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b.
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Interface enp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382824.8319] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Apr 28 05:33:44 UB gnome-session[1645]: message repeated 3 times: [ (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed]
Apr 28 05:34:53 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: BOOTP(enp3s0) 00:21:b7:91:00:ea no address configured
Apr 28 05:34:53 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: BOOTP(enp3s0) 00:21:b7:91:00:ea no address configured
Apr 28 05:34:56 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPDISCOVER(enp3s0) 169.254.1.107 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:34:56 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPOFFER(enp3s0) 10.42.0.231 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:35:00 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPDISCOVER(enp3s0) 169.254.1.107 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:35:00 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPOFFER(enp3s0) 10.42.0.231 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:35:08 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPDISCOVER(enp3s0) 169.254.1.107 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:35:08 UB dnsmasq-dhcp[1209]: DHCPOFFER(enp3s0) 10.42.0.231 00:21:b7:91:00:ea
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB kernel: [143290.822729] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.3923] device (enp2s0): link connected
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.3934] device (enp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.3956] policy: auto-activating connection 'Built-in ethernet'
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.4000] device (enp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Built-in ethernet' (91c9448c-6ed0-3a75-8724-25adc0f0819d)
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.4058] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.4059] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.4064] device (enp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.4067] device (enp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.4071] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382943.4095] dhcp4 (enp2s0): dhclient started with pid 17279
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB dhclient[17279]: DHCPREQUEST of 24.5.188.10 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x548aa40d)
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Apr 28 05:35:43 UB gnome-session[1645]: message repeated 3 times: [ (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed]
Apr 28 05:35:45 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b.
Apr 28 05:35:45 UB avahi-daemon[795]: New relevant interface enp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 28 05:35:45 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Registering new address record for fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b on enp2s0.*.
Apr 28 05:35:45 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382945.9558] dhcp6 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 28 05:35:45 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382945.9595] dhcp6 (enp2s0): dhclient started with pid 17288
Apr 28 05:35:45 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:35:45] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 28 05:35:46 UB dhclient[17279]: DHCPREQUEST of 24.5.188.10 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x548aa40d)
Apr 28 05:35:46 UB dhclient[17288]: XMT: Confirm on enp2s0, interval 1070ms.
Apr 28 05:35:46 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:35:46] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 28 05:35:47 UB dhclient[17288]: XMT: Confirm on enp2s0, interval 2190ms.
Apr 28 05:35:49 UB dhclient[17288]: XMT: Confirm on enp2s0, interval 4330ms.
Apr 28 05:35:54 UB dhclient[17279]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x660d7810)
Apr 28 05:35:54 UB dhclient[17288]: XMT: Confirm on enp2s0, interval 2410ms.
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB dhclient[17288]: Max retransmission duration exceeded.
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.5971]   valid_lft 345600
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.5978]   preferred_lft 345600
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.5979]   address 2001:558:6045:bf:393a:c4b4:7335:5239
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.5979]   nameserver '2001:558:feed::1'
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.5980]   nameserver '2001:558:feed::2'
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.5980] dhcp6 (enp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound, event ID="7e:b4:3e:ff|1493336309"
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:35:56] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.6015] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB dbus[798]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.6033] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.6040] device (enp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.6044] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB dbus[798]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp6-change' [enp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp6-change' [enp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.6493] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.6496] policy: set 'Built-in ethernet' (enp2s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.6500] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB dnsmasq[1318]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB dnsmasq[1318]: using nameserver 2001:558:feed::1#53
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB dnsmasq[1318]: using nameserver 2001:558:feed::2#53
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382956.6659] device (enp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [enp2s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [enp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:35:56] The default IPv6 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:35:56] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:35:56] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB gnome-session[1645]: (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB gnome-session[1645]: message repeated 3 times: [ (nm-applet:1882): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed]
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 28 05:35:56 UB systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 28 05:35:57 UB gnome-session[1645]: (deja-dup-monitor:2359): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 126 was not found when attempting to remove it
Apr 28 05:35:57 UB dhclient[17279]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x660d7810)
Apr 28 05:35:58 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b.
Apr 28 05:35:58 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address 2001:558:6045:bf:393a:c4b4:7335:5239.
Apr 28 05:35:58 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Registering new address record for 2001:558:6045:bf:393a:c4b4:7335:5239 on enp2s0.*.
Apr 28 05:35:58 UB avahi-daemon[795]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::17a8:5da8:40ba:4d2b on enp2s0.
Apr 28 05:36:01 UB dhclient[17279]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x660d7810)
Apr 28 05:36:08 UB dhclient[17279]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x660d7810)
Apr 28 05:36:17 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:36:17] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Apr 28 05:36:23 UB dhclient[17279]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x660d7810)
Apr 28 05:36:28 UB NetworkManager[841]: <warn>  [1493382988.8106] dhcp4 (enp2s0): request timed out
Apr 28 05:36:28 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382988.8106] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Apr 28 05:36:28 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382988.8275] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 17279
Apr 28 05:36:28 UB NetworkManager[841]: <info>  [1493382988.8276] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed timeout -> done
Apr 28 05:36:29 UB whoopsie[782]: [05:36:29] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
```

Here's the routing table (internet on enp2s0 and LAN on enp3s0):

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         172.21.22.1     0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
    0.0.0.0         24.5.176.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
    10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0
    24.5.176.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0
    69.252.97.6     24.5.176.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp2s0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0
    172.21.22.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     50     0        0 tun0
    216.151.183.10  24.5.176.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp2s0
```

Comment: What type of vpn do you use? How did you configured it?

Comment: I'm running OpenVPN. Config looks like:`client
dev tun
proto udp
remote XXX.ipvanish.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
persist-remote-ip
ca ca.ipvanish.com.crt
verify-x509-name XXX.ipvanish.com name
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-DSS-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA`

Comment: Can u please add the output of ps -aux and ip route list  and ip link and ip address , while you are running the vpn connection?

Comment: I'm hitting a length limit on the post with ps -aux output. Is there something in particular you're looking for?

Comment: The system is basically running 16.04 and OpenVPN with default configs.

Comment: dhclient instances and anything related to openvpn, networkmanager... that's all that is comming through my mind right now. And please check if you have connectivity with the remote side of vpn while you are connected ( with ping ).

Comment: And ping also your default gateway (24.5.176.1) while you are connected to the vpn

Comment: And check if you have any firewall filtering rules ( iptables -nvL ) and if you have, please add the output to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Install `network-manager-opnevpn-gnome`. You will then be able to configure OpenVPN through NetworkManager on 'Network Settings'.

Comment: small typo there network-manager-opnevpn-gnome shoud be network-manager-opnenpn-gnome.